# Bower hangs after checkout step of Install command.

Tags: bower, bower-install, github-enterprise

I'm a github enterprise user and I'm using bower to point an internal repository to manage dependencies.

I have set up a repo and included a bower.json file in the root directory. It looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "Axis",
  "main": "Axis.js",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "authors": [
    "Nick Randall"
  ],
  "description": "Chart Axis",
  "keywords": [
    "d3",
    "d3.chart",
    "axis"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "ignore": [
    "**/.*",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "test",
    "tests"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "d3": "~3.4.6",
    "d3.chart": "~0.2.0",
    "lodash": "~2.4.1"
  }
}
```

I'm trying to install the repo above as a dependency in a new project using "bower install Org/Axis" and the process hangs after the "Checkout" step. Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

My .bowerrc file looks like this:

```
{
  "shorthand-resolver": "https://git.company.com/{{owner}}/{{package}}'.git"
}
```

and this is the response I get from the command line:

```
bower Axis#*           not-cached https://git.company.com/Org/Axis.git#*
bower Axis#*           resolve https://git.company.com/Org/Axis.git#*
bower Axis#*           checkout v1.1.1
```

after that it just hangs there and never progresses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this was a dumb mistake. I had my `.bowerrc` in the wrong location. Once I moved it to the root of my project, everything started working. I hope this helps somebody else!

Answer (score 0):

About a year ago, there was an issue with bower hanging due to problems with the version of unzip.  To see if your hanging may have the same cause you might try to install one of the dependencies individually.  If an individual install doesn't hang you may have the same issue as before -- it occurred in the presence of certain combinations of node version and bower version.  To try and load individually, consider for example:

`bower install https://github.com/lodash/lodash.git`